# Syntax error in mysql backup script

Tags: mysql, shell, backup

i am using a script in my macbook pro to backup Mysql databases of  my development apps, and its working fine.
But i tried to use it in my ubuntu server test and gave this error :
**Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "done")**

On this line of code:

```
table_types=($($MYSQL -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS -e 
"show table status from $DB" | awk '{ if ($2 == "MyISAM" || $2 == "InnoDB") print $1,$2}'))
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to open a bracket "(". Try this:

```
table_types=($($MYSQL -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS -e "show table status from $DB" | awk '({ if ($2 == "MyISAM" || $2 == "InnoDB") print $1,$2}'))
```